# pdflatex / xelatex -output-directory and subdirectories when using \include

Tags: compiling, auxiliary-files, folders

When I include a file from a subdirectory with `\include{subdir/sub}` and compile the file with `pdflatex -output-directory .tex_test/ main.tex`, `pdflatex` complains, that it can't write to `.tex_test/subdir/sub.aux`. (Same happens with `xelatex`)

Is there a way to automatically create the necessary file structure in the `output-directory`? Of course it would also be ok, if `sub.aux` would be written directly to `.tex_test/`, but I guess that is not possible...

Full MWE:
`./main.tex` contains:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Main Document

\include{subdir/sub}
\end{document}
```

and `./subdir/sub.tex` contains just anything. More importantly the directory `.tex_test/` exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just recreate in the invisible directory the same tree as your "visible" one: I tried and creating a `subdir` directory inside `.tex_test` worked.

Actually I changed the names, but it's just the same. Here's the log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./canasub.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, 
welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(.canaout/canasub.aux (.canaout/canasub/sub.aux)) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/te
xmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./canasub/sub.tex) [2]
(.canaout/canasub.aux (.canaout/canasub/sub.aux)) )</usr/local/texlive/2012/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on .canaout/canasub.pdf (2 pages, 13249 bytes).
Transcript written on .canaout/canasub.log.
```

As you see, the `sub.aux` file is read in from `.canasub/canasub`

---

With shell escape enabled, you can create the directory:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@include\include
\def\include#1{\include@aux#1\@nil}
\def\include@aux#1/#2\@nil{\@mkdir{#1}\latex@include{#1/#2}}
\ifnum\pdfshellescape=\@ne
  \def\@mkdir#1{\immediate\write18{mkdir -p .tex_test/#1}}
\else
  \def\@mkdir{\typeout{Expect errors}}
\fi

\begin{document}
Main Document

\include{canasub/sub}
\end{document}
```

Here I assume a Unix system (I don't know how to create a directory on Windows) and that all `\include` commands have the same structure

```
\include{subdir/file}
```

It should be quite easy to cope with different patterns. Of course you have to add `-shell-escape` to the call of `pdflatex`.

However the `.tex_test` part must be hard encoded, as TeX has no internal knowledge of the output directory.

Comment: That's why I wrote "Is there a way to automatically create the necessary file structure in the output-directory?"...

Comment: @canaaerus No: TeX doesn't create directories. You *might* use shell-escape for this, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Shell help is acceptable. But then `TeX` would have to output the directory structure somehow.

Answer (score 5):

WinEdt 7 is able to do what you need automatically.

Simply create a subfolder named `TeXAux` in your main folder and WinEdt takes care of creating subfolders automatically.

You don't even need to pass `-output-directory` to the command-line.

Answer (score 3):

I use a Makefile for my LaTeX document. This command creates the directory structure of the root directory in the output-directory:

```
mkdir -p ${OUTPUTDIRECTORY}
for DIR in $(shell find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec basename '{}' \;) ; do      mkdir -p ${OUTPUTDIRECTORY}/$$DIR ;     done
```

`-maxdepth`defines how deep `find`goes to look for directories. I got this command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107945/how-to-loop-over-directories-in-linux).

Using a Rakefile or Python script would probably make this even easier. There doesn't seem to be a way for `pdflatex`to automatically create the necessary directories.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)